# write img tags in a specific stack order

Tags: php

Let's say `imgT` folder has five images - from `01.jpg` to `05.jpg`.

```
function givemeG($path) {
$files = glob($path . '*.jpg');
$cs=" class=\"act\"";
foreach($files as $img) { 
    echo "<img" . $cs . " src=" . "\"" . $img . "\"" . " alt=\"img\">";
    $cs="";
    echo "\n";
}
}
$path = "imgT/";
givemeG($path);
```

This will produce the following:

```
<img class="act" src="imgT/01.jpg" alt="img">
<img src="imgT/02.jpg" alt="img">
<img src="imgT/03.jpg" alt="img">
<img src="imgT/04.jpg" alt="img">
<img src="imgT/05.jpg" alt="img">
```

Is there a way to get the following result:

```
<img class="act" src="imgT/01.jpg" alt="img">  // lowest number (01)
<img src="imgT/05.jpg" alt="img">  //  highest number (05)
<img src="imgT/02.jpg" alt="img">  // next lowest (02)
<img src="imgT/04.jpg" alt="img">  // next highest (04)
<img src="imgT/03.jpg" alt="img">  // next lowest (03)
... etc following the same pattern if there is more images.
```

I hope it's clear - from outside (lowest and highest) to inside (next lowest and next highest) of imagined array of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do what you want: [(on codepad)](http://codepad.org/p2OEqWQA)

```
<?php
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$len = count($arr);
$even = $len%2==0; //Are there an even number of elements in the array?
$middle = $even ? ceil($len/2) : floor($len/2); //Gets point at which we stop
foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
    if($key==$middle && $even) break; //If it's an even counted array, and we've reached our 'middle' stop processing
    echo $value;
    echo "\r\n";
    if($key < $middle) //If we're not at the middle yet, find the appropriate element from the end of the array
    {
        echo $arr[$len-($key+1)];
        echo "\r\n";
    }
    else if($key==$middle) break;
}
```

It basically just does a normal loop through, but for each one, it takes the element that's the same distance from the end as this one is from the beginning.

Let me know if I've not made the method clear enough.